# How we remove object from an Array based on another array in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have two arrays like this:

```js
var skillArray = [
{ID: 1, name: "الغطس"},
{ID: 2, name: "الحريق"},
{ID: 3, name: "المعالجة"},
{ID: 4, name: "الميكانيكا"},
{ID: 5, name: "السيول"},
{ID: 6, name: "التغريز"},
{ID: 7, name: "الكهرباء"},
{ID: 8, name: "الاحتفالات"},
{ID: 9, name: "المناسبات"},
{ID: 10, name: "الصلاة"}
]

var splitstr = ["9", "7"]
```

As you can see, ID 9 & 7 match and I want to be able to remove them from skillArray. How would I write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved simply using `includes` as follows -

```js
var skillArray = [
    {ID: 1, name: "الغطس"},
    {ID: 2, name: "الحريق"},
    {ID: 3, name: "المعالجة"},
    {ID: 4, name: "الميكانيكا"},
    {ID: 5, name: "السيول"},
    {ID: 6, name: "التغريز"},
    {ID: 7, name: "الكهرباء"},
    {ID: 8, name: "الاحتفالات"},
    {ID: 9, name: "المناسبات"},
    {ID: 10, name: "الصلاة"}
]

var splitstr = ["9", "7"];

skillArray.forEach((obj, index) => {
  if(splitstr.includes(obj['ID'].toString())) {
      skillArray.splice(index, 1);
  }
});

console.log(skillArray);
```

**Note:** **`toString()`** is necessary to convert a number to a string if you want to compare a number with a string.

Answer (score 4):

Use `skillArray.filter()` for each element of `splitstr`.

And you have to convert type to compare since `splitstr` has elements as string.

```js
var skillArray = [
{ID: 1, name: "الغطس"},
{ID: 2, name: "الحريق"},
{ID: 3, name: "المعالجة"},
{ID: 4, name: "الميكانيكا"},
{ID: 5, name: "السيول"},
{ID: 6, name: "التغريز"},
{ID: 7, name: "الكهرباء"},
{ID: 8, name: "الاحتفالات"},
{ID: 9, name: "المناسبات"},
{ID: 10, name: "الصلاة"}
]

var splitstr = ["9", "7"]

var arr = skillArray.filter(e => !splitstr.includes('' + e.ID))

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example :

```js
var skillArray = [
    {ID: 1, name: "الغطس"},
    {ID: 2, name: "الحريق"},
    {ID: 3, name: "المعالجة"},
    {ID: 4, name: "الميكانيكا"},
    {ID: 5, name: "السيول"},
    {ID: 6, name: "التغريز"},
    {ID: 7, name: "الكهرباء"},
    {ID: 8, name: "الاحتفالات"},
    {ID: 9, name: "المناسبات"},
    {ID: 10, name: "الصلاة"}
]

var splitstr = ["9", "7"]

for (var i = 0; i < splitstr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < skillArray.length; j++) {
        if (splitstr[i] == skillArray[j]['ID']) {
            skillArray.splice(j, 1);
        }
    }
}

console.log(skillArray);
```

The `splice` method can be used to add or remove elements from an array. The first argument specifies the location at which to begin adding or removing elements. The second argument specifies the number of elements to remove.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to modify the same array, then use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

And [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the index of a matching item to be removed.

```js
var skillArray = [
{ID: 1, name: "الغطس"},
{ID: 2, name: "الحريق"},
{ID: 3, name: "المعالجة"},
{ID: 4, name: "الميكانيكا"},
{ID: 5, name: "السيول"},
{ID: 6, name: "التغريز"},
{ID: 7, name: "الكهرباء"},
{ID: 8, name: "الاحتفالات"},
{ID: 9, name: "المناسبات"},
{ID: 10, name: "الصلاة"}
]

var splitstr = ["9", "7"]

splitstr.forEach(item => {
  const i = skillArray.findIndex(skill => skill.ID == item);
  if(i > -1) {
       skillArray.splice(i, 1)
  }
})

console.log(skillArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var skillArray = [
{ID: 1, name: "الغطس"},
{ID: 2, name: "الحريق"},
{ID: 3, name: "المعالجة"},
{ID: 4, name: "الميكانيكا"},
{ID: 5, name: "السيول"},
{ID: 6, name: "التغريز"},
{ID: 7, name: "الكهرباء"},
{ID: 8, name: "الاحتفالات"},
{ID: 9, name: "المناسبات"},
{ID: 10, name: "الصلاة"}
]

var splitstr = ["9", "7"]

const removeSkills = (source, removeList) => {
  return source.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    if(!removeList.includes(curr.ID.toString()) ){
      return prev.concat(curr)
    }
    return prev
  }, [])
}
const result = removeSkills(skillArray, splitstr)
console.log(result)
```